# How do I find out which Epic Games account is linked to my Nintendo account so I can unlink it?

Tags: epic-games-launcher, nintendo-account

When I am trying to link my Epic Games account to my Nintendo account (Nintendo Switch), it mentions that it is already linked to another Epic Games account.

Is there a way to know which Epic Games account my Nintendo is linked to so I can unlink it?